# Add 0 starting and ending values to histogram line (matplotlib)

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'd like to have the line superimposed over this histogram to go to zero at both ends. I assumed that adding 0 values to the start and end of the data arrays would suffice, but this doesn't seem to work.

[image: plot]

```
plt.style.use('seaborn-white')
data = np.array(sizes_)
n, bins, _ = plt.hist(data, bins=bins, alpha=0.2, density=True)
plt.grid(axis='y', alpha=0.5)
plt.xlim([0, 500])
bin_centers = 0.5 * (bins[1:] + bins[:-1])

## Tried this but doesn't work
np.insert(bin_centers, 0, 0)
np.append(bin_centers, 500)
np.insert(n, 0, 0)
np.append(n, 0)
##

plt.plot(bin_centers, n)
plt.xlabel('length (nts)')
plt.ylabel('frequency')
plt.title('Length Distribution')
plt.savefig(outfile)
```

Any ideas how I can do this?

Comment: neither `numpy.append` nor `numpy.insert` modify any of the original arrays. Instead they return a newly created array. You would want to plot this new array, `newarray = np.append(oldarray, furthervalues)`

Comment: Boom. That's it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to save the arrays after inserting. Moreover, you need to append one pair of x-y values at the end of the arrays. Following is one way of doing it using a sample data set since you did not provide a MCVE

```
plt.style.use('seaborn-white')
np.random.seed(121)
sizes_ = np.random.randint(2, 100, 50)
data = np.array(sizes_)
n, bins, _ = plt.hist(data, bins=20, alpha=0.2, density=True)
plt.grid(axis='y', alpha=0.5)
bin_centers = 0.5 * (bins[1:] + bins[:-1])

bin_diff = np.diff(bin_centers)[-1]

bin_centers = np.insert(bin_centers, 0, 0)
bin_centers = np.insert(bin_centers, len(bin_centers), bin_centers[-1] + bin_diff)

n = np.insert(n, 0, 0)
n = np.insert(n, len(n), 0)

plt.plot(bin_centers, n)
plt.xlabel('length (nts)')
plt.ylabel('frequency')
plt.title('Length Distribution')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The `np.append()` and `np.insert()` are not in-place functions, they return the result and you should assign that to your variable (`bin_centers = np.insert(bin_centers, 0, bins[0])`)

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

plt.style.use('seaborn-white')
data = np.array([15, 20, 14, 10, 20, 21, 18, 8])
n, bins, _ = plt.hist(data, alpha=0.2, density=True)
plt.grid(axis='y', alpha=0.5)
plt.xlim([0, 30])
bin_centers = 0.5 * (bins[1:] + bins[:-1])

bin_centers = np.insert(bin_centers, 0, bins[0])
bin_centers = np.append(bin_centers, bins[-1])
n = np.insert(n, 0, 0)
n = np.append(n, 0)

plt.plot(bin_centers, n)
plt.xlabel('length (nts)')
plt.ylabel('frequency')
plt.title('Length Distribution')
plt.show()
```

[image]